# Icons8 custom icon font for iOS

Tags: ios, fonts

I got an icons8 ttf file to use custom icons for iOS app. Font name changed based on the full name which i got from file info. But I'm unable to fetch icon from ttf file, with same ttf it's working cool in android. Icons8 providing the icons for iOS but no where I get the example.

```
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Icons8" size:100]];
[label setText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"&#xf100;"]];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: check once in the font family the name is available or not

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in Swift work for me with icons8 ttf :

```
label.text = String(format: "%C", 61710)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just verify you have copied your "Icons8.ttf" font file in

> Project Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

See:[image: drag/add your font file here]

And also do not forget to add the file name in Info.plist

[image: add font name here]

Comment: does that font has an icon for specific font style only Eg: Regular, Medium

Comment: no specific style for font. you can check icons8 website

Comment: if possible share your font file on dropbox

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6lvky3vnu130xc/icons.zip?dl=0 , here you can get the .ttf file

Comment: i tried, somehow i think there issue with string encoding, i tried from another library, dont' know how but  NSArray *arraForString = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
    [label setText:[arraForString objectAtIndex:0]]; is assigning sound icon to label...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112268/discussion-between-suhas-patil-and-code-cracker).

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you use *ttf for iOS.*
You may consider **PDF** instead; we support it and it works great with Xcode.

Another option is to donwload PNGs of various sizes:

1. Create a collection and add the icons there
2. Choose PNG size and download all icons at once
3. Repeat with sizes x2 and x3

Comment: thanks @ivan . actually the problem is i got this ttf from android team , they are using ttf they said.

Comment: it would be more helpful if you provide any reference @ivan boyko